# what statement is not true about a unique index

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique

I'm learning MySQL. I came across some multiple-choice questions.
If I doubted what the answer was or was not convinced it's correct I started searching google, stackoverflow and the mysql site.
However for some I still couldn't confirm what the correct answer was.

Question:
all of the following statements are true about a unique index except which one?
A. it must be unique for all columns of a table
B. it should not be explicitly defined for tables
C. It must be created only for columns having PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints.
D. It cannot be created by itself
E. It cannot be ensured that the combination of all values contained in the index are unique

Proposed answer: E.

My thoughts:

A. I really have no clue what they mean by it. But in this question it should be a correct statement. Can someone make this clear?
B. defined for tables? a unique index is on a table column. And by default non unique values are possible so it should be explicitly defined
C. Looks correct. Primary key is unique as well so therefor an index should be built by MySQL (however not explicitly)
D. wut? another answer that doesn't make any sense to me (am I stupid? :S)
E. Combination of values? No then it can't be ensured that these combinations of the values of a column are unique. If it is combinations of the different columns that might be combined in a primary key: then it can be ensured otherwise there is no use for a UNIQUE index.

Mostly I'm able to have a preferred answer when in doubt, however here I have no clue:s

This one is really driving me nuts:s Is this just a language barrier or ...

If you have any remark about this question/answer or for any of my remarks I'm happy to hear it!

Comment: Where did this question come from? At first glance, it seems to me that all but one of the answers are false (or, as you point out, nonsensical).

Answer (score 0):

These answers do not makes sense:

> A. it must be unique for all columns of a table

A unique index is generally defined on a subset of columns of a table.  A given index would only apply to all columns if it were defined that way.  Hence, this is false.

> B. it should not be explicitly defined for tables

Why would the construct exist if it shouldn't be used?  Unique indexes are quite useful.  One could argue that it is not defined on "tables" but on "columns in tables", but that seems too nuanced for this question.

> C. It must be created only for columns having PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints.

This comes close to being true.  You could argue that creating a unique index is equivalent to creating a unique constraint.  However, they are different syntactic constructs for doing the same thing.  Furthermore, *you* wouldn't create a unique index for a column with a unique constraint, because the database does it for you.

> D. It cannot be created by itself

I don't know what this is supposed to mean.  In a sense, it cannot be created "by itself" because it needs a table to be defined on.

> E. It cannot be ensured that the combination of all values contained in the index are unique

This is true, because NULL values are allowed to be duplicated:

> ```
> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
> must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
> key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE
> index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.][1]
> ```

I would read that only (e) is unambiguously true.  Options (c) and (d) come close, depending on the interpretation.  Options (a) and (b) seem false to my reading.

You may want to look somewhere else for such questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer! It's really appreciated and learnful (also in clear correct english ;)). You have a point that I should go look somewhere else for questions as this isn't the first one I'm so confused about.